# How to make Timer that can looping in different duration automatically?

Tags: android, loops, timer

I had made some codes for creating a timer, like below this.

```
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override           
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            timer=new CountDownTimer(totaltime, 1000) {

        @Override           
        public void onTick(long lefttime) {
        longseconds=lefttime/1000;                               
       notif.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds/60)+ ":" + 
         String.format("%02d",seconds%60)); 
                            }




        @Override           
        public void onFinish() {
            notif.setText("DONE");
            }
                }.start();
            }


            });
```

That code is for only counting same duration infinitely. But now, I want to count a different duration for some loops. For example :

If loop 1 is timeout, so automatically begin to repeat counting duration but in different duration, like below this

Loop 1 = 30 sec.

Loop 2 = 20 sec.

Loop 3 = 10 sec.

etc..

How do that ?

Please help me, I always stucked in same problem.
Thank you for your helping.. :)

Comment: do u have the number of loops and duration fixed?

Comment: yes, similar like what I said in that question. So, loop in my project has 3 numbers. If it has finished,timer will stop. Do u have idea ?